# Let $A=\{3,4\}$ be a subset of $S=\{1,2,..., 6\}$. Let $n\in S$. Prove if $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ is even, then $n\in A$.

Tags: proof-writing

Let $A=\{3,4\}$ be a subset of $S=\{1,2,..., 6\}$. Let $n\in S$. Prove if $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ is even, then $n\in A$.

I know this needs to be a proof by cases, and it should be "Assume $n$ is even. By definition $n=2k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. From here we note that $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=\frac{(2k)^2(2k+1)^2}{4}$." From here I am not finding it to be even or odd when it is simplified. I get $k^2(2k+1)^2$, which is not helpful.

Comment: If the wording of the question is exactly as you stated, since there are only $6$ elements in $S$, you can check their $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4$ one by one.

Comment: either $n$ or $n+1$ is even, so, if $8$ divides $n^2(n+1)^2$, then $8$ divides $n^2$ or $8$ divides $(n+1)^2$; if $8$ divides $N^2$, then $4$ divides $N$

Comment: Yet another way is to notice that from the well-known formula for the sum of integers we have $n^2(n+1)^2/4 = (1 + 2 + \ldots + n)^2$ which is even iff $(1+2+\ldots +n)$ is even.

Comment: Just show $n=1,2,5,6$ then $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4$ is odd.  That's all you have to do.

Comment: Note:  $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4$ being even is the same thing as $n^2(n+1)^2$ being divisible by $8$.  Only one of $n$ or $n+1$ is even so we have either $8$ dividing $n^2$ or $8$ dividing $(n+1)^2$.  If $8=2^3$ divides $M^2$ what does that say about $M$?  What feature do the numbers $3,4$ have that $1,2,5,6$ don't?

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac {n^2(n+1)^2}4 =2k$ is even.  Then $n^2(n+1)^2 =8k$.  Now one of $n$ or $(n+1)$ is odd and the other is even. $8$ divides $n^2(n+1)^2$ so either $8$ divides $n^2$ or $8$ divide $(n+1)^2$.

If $8$ divides $n^2$ what does that say about the divisibility of $n$?  What does $4$ have that $2$ and $6$ do not?

If $8$ divides $(n+1)^2$ what doest that say about the divisibility of $n+1$?  What does $3+1$ have that $1+1$ and $5+1$ do not?